# TCHAR setting in the Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qmake

I am working with some legacy project which uses **Qt 4**. It is cross-platform, but I am interesting in its ***Windows*** part. I am trying to upgrade it for **Qt 5**, but I have faced with a problem. I have a lot of errors like:

```
error: 'BOOL SomeFunctionW(LPCWSTR)': C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [123]' to 'LPCWSTR'
```

Which **qmake** settings should I use to make compiler interpret:

- `TCHAR` (and so on) as `char` (and so on);
- `SomeFunction` as `SomeFunctionA` instead of `SomeFunctionW`?

I use ***Visual Studio 2015***'s compiler.

**UPDATE:**

Instead of `SomeFunctionW` I have:

````
error: C2664: 'DWORD GetModuleFileNameW(HMODULE,LPWSTR,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
error: C2664: 'DWORD GetEnvironmentVariableW(LPCWSTR,LPWSTR,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [14]' to 'LPCWSTR'
error: C2664: 'UINT GetWindowsDirectoryW(LPWSTR,UINT)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
error: C2664: 'DWORD GetCurrentDirectoryW(DWORD,LPWSTR)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char [260]' to 'LPWSTR'
error: C2664: 'BOOL SetCurrentDirectoryW(LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [260]' to 'LPCWSTR'```
````

**UPDATE #2**:

Some artificial example

***main.cpp***

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    char buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
    GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(buffer), buffer);
    return a.exec();
}
```

***sample.pro*** (autogenerated)

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = winapi_sample
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

How should I update **sample.pro** file to compile the sample project?

Comment: Actually, we use Qt (on Windows) to make our code portable. `SomeFunctionW()`/`SomeFunctionA()` sounds like win32 API. These are exactly the functions which we want to ban from our code (and hence are using Qt...) Btw., I'm afraid you have to provide a little bit more context for a reasonable answer.

Comment: Define `_MBCS` and `MBCS`. Undefine `_UNICODE` and `UNICODE`. Not recommended, but there you have it.

Comment: It depends on how you compile your project: as unicode or ansi. So, make sure you don't have `_UNICODE` defined, so `TCHAR` will be treated as `char`.

Comment: @Scheff Yes, the project contains a Qt part as GUI tools and some define guarded platform specific parts. So there is some WinAPI code for Windows. `SomeFunction` is a WinAPI function which has two versions: `SomeFunctionA` (for `char`-strings) and `SomeFunctionW` (`wchar_t`-strings).

Comment: @IInspectable I have added `DEFINES += _MBCS`, `DEFINES += MBCS`, `DEFINES -= _UNICODE`, `DEFINES -= UNICODE` to the pro file, but it has not helped.

Comment: @vahancho I have not found any _UNICODE/UNICODE macro in the code

Comment: Please provide the REAL error message. What is the REAL `SomeFunction` named? Is the error happening when compiling Qt itself, or in your code that is trying to call into Qt?

Comment: Ah, OK. We do it similar, except that (as already recommended) I prefer to call everything from win32 API explicitly with `W` suffix. We use internally UTF-8 exclusively as this can be handled simply with standard character/string functions. AFAIK, Qt uses internally some Unicode based encoding and has best support with `QString::fromUtf8()` and `QString::toUtf8()`. For the win32 API wrapper, we use UTF-8 to UTF-16 conversion to feed win32 functions (and reverse for retrievals) as this can be done by simple bit shifting. (So, it's completely "localization agnostic" what I like very much.)

Comment: Dear @RemyLebeau, I have provided errors example as you have requested. Also I have added an example to understand the problem. Should I add anymore?

Comment: @LexSergeev like Scheff said, Qt uses Unicode UTF-16 strings, not `char` strings. But in your own code, when using `TCHAR` based APIs, like the generic `GetCurrentDirectory()`, use `TCHAR` strings to match, not `char` strings, eg: `TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 }; GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, buffer);` Otherwise, when using `char ` strings, call the `A` version of the functions directly, eg: `char buffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 }; GetCurrentDirectoryA(MAX_PATH, buffer);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Do you take into account, that it is **an artificial sample**? I have a huge legacy project, and I wouldn't like to do thousands `char -> TCHAR`, `SomeFunction -> SomeFunctionA` or similar replacements in the code base. Why do you ignore the question about **pro** file? If my problem was in the sample, I wouldn't ask a question here

Comment: @LexSergeev "*Why do you ignore the question about pro file?*" - because I don't know what a `.pro` file is, how it is generated, or how it is used. I deal with  *coding* issues, not *makefile* issues

Comment: @RemyLebeau Are you kidding me? It is difficult to imagine a developer who doesn't _deal_ with build systems. **pro** is a file for _**qmake**_ which is build system  for **Qt**. This question is about **Qt** and **qmake**. If you have never worked with **Qt**, you will just waste your time.

Comment: @LexSergeev "*It is difficult to imagine a developer who doesn't deal with build systems*" - well, now you have met one

Comment: @IInspectable Your comment was right. It helped me but it was necessary to delete build folder. Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it

Comment: `How should I update sample.pro file to compile the sample project?` Simply `DEFINES -= UNICODE` should suffice (unless you're actually using `_T()` macro or other "underscored" stuff from `tchar.h`).

Comment: @Matt Yes, it was a solution. But for some unclear reasons it didn't work until I had removed the build folder and started from the scratch

Comment: `it didn't work until I had removed the build folder ` Ah, such bs happens all the time. So in case of any trouble try `make distclean qmake first` first.